# Splitting and removing a file?

Tags: linux, split

I am currently trying to split a large (9GB file) into smaller chunks to read into a database one at a time. Unfortunately, I only have a 20GB SSD in the machine (it is a cheap VPS) and so I only have 8GB free, hence splitting the file so I can read and delete. While I did think of scaling the VPS up for a short period of time apparently I cannot do that at this time, so I was stuck looking for other options.

I was wondering, therefore, if it is possible to use the split command to break a file into say 9 parts while incrementally removing the old file so that it could fit, instead of copying it (as split usually does).

I have looked in the manpages and see no reference to this process.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider instead compressing that file (on your Linux laptop) with `bzip2 bigdump.sql`, then remote copying it `scp bigdump.sql.bz2 remotevps:` then, on the remote VPS: `bzcat bigdump.bz2 | mysql` ?

Comment: Otherwise, learn about `sed`

Comment: Nifty idea. Might be a bit slow due to my upload speed, but I will get that going. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tail -c 1G bigfile >lastchunk` to save the last GB from the bigfile into lastchunk, then `truncate -s -1G bigfile` to remove the last GB from bigfile (and free the disk space). Repeat until you have only handy sized chunks.

Of course, the problem is how easy it is to get wrong. If the truncate removes a different number of bytes compared to the number of bytes read out by tail you will either lose bytes or have duplicates resulting in corrupt data. Using multipliers like G should reduce the possibility of harm. Still, have a backup and do a test run before.

Comment: But if the bigfile is an SQL dump the split boundaries should be at end of some SQL statement! Perhaps use [csplit(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html)